# omp to sum eigen matrix

Tags: eigen, openmp

For each run, I wanted to sum grad to overall_grad. to prevent racing condition, I used atomic. But the compiler says:

```
error: invalid expression type for ‘#pragma omp atomic’
```

code

```
#pragma omp atomic
overall_grad.h +=  grad.h;
overall_grad.w +=  grad.w;
```

data type

```
struct Grad {
     Eigen::MatrixXd h;
     Eigen::MatrixXd w;
};
```

Does omp support += only for primitive type? How can Eigen matrix be summed here? Thanks!

Note, I'm not using parallel functionality provided by Eigen library, just run a parallel for over all samples, and update overall_grad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes atomic operations are only for a few native types. In your case you need to use a critical section:

```
#pragma omp critical 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific? Thanks!